# Issues access a CakePhp site after migrating to apache 2.4.10

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp

I recently migrated a cakePHP app to another debian version but getting the above error. The apache version is 2.4 and below is what i have in the htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

On the browser it displays the following error;

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at sysad@sysad.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

When I check, the apache logs I get the following

```
htaccess: FilterProvider takes three arguments, filter-name provider-name match-expression,
```

Comment: Have you done any research yet? Have you read the [**upgrade guide**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html)? Any attempts to fix the problem? A quick google search for the error message should bring up quite a few results, you are by far not the first one encountering that error.

Comment: Its fixed. Replaced the filterProvider with 
<IfModule mod_deflate.c> 
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE 
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpg|png|ico|zip|gz|mp4|flv)$ no-gzip
</IfModule>

Comment: check for `mod_rewrite` on/off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fixed, replaced the FilterPovider mod_deflate.c with the following below

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c> 
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE 
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpg|png|ico|zip|gz|mp4|flv)$ no-gzip
 </IfModule>
```